# Robust pthread mutexes - portability across platforms

Tags: c, pthreads, posix, mutex

I want to use shared memory across processes and wanted to use the [robust pthread mutexes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_setrobust.html) for the same, because, they can help with the problem when a process dies holding the mutex. My only concern is, are they portable across different platforms - different versions of linux and then on different operating systems too? The earlier versions of `pthread.h` have just the `_NP` versions of`PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST` attribute. I could not find much documentation about the portability online.

Would really appreciate any repsonse on the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIX mandates `pthread_mutexattr_getrobust`. And hence all [POSIX compliant systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#POSIX-oriented_operating_systems) should support it. Also note that `pthread_mutexattr_getrobust` was first introduced in Issue 7. ie [POSIX:2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#POSIX:2008) Do check this on the systems where you want to port.

On the latest linux variants, I think you should be safe.